# PostgreSQL 12+ ignoring datestyle setting in the postgresql.conf

Tags: postgresql

I can not set the German datestyle format in Postgres (or any other than ISO).

I have set `datestyle = 'German'` in postgresql.conf and restarted the service and still `show datestyle;` reports 'ISO, DMY'.

Tried on:

- Ubuntu 20, Postgres 12
- Windows 10, Postgres 13

Also tried `datestyle = 'SQL'` with the same effect, still 'ISO, DMY'.

Tried `ALTER DATABASE database_name SET datestyle TO "German";`, even restarted - also does not work.
The only thing working is per session statement `set datestyle='german'` but I want to change it permanently.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting in `postgresql.conf` must be overridden somewhere. Look at `pg_settings`:

```
SELECT setting, source, sourcefile, sourceline
FROM pg_settings
WHERE name = 'DateStyle';
```

The `source` column will tell you where your setting comes from. Perhaps your client overrides the server setting.

Comment: Worked like a charm. The source was "session" and the culprit was pgAdmin - it was setting the datestyle on his own.
It was actually working fine from our code, but we were checking in pgAdmin and thought it was not working...
Thanks.